# Partitioning Polygons layer to smaller partitions

Tags: arcobjects, polygon, java

I Have a huge polygon layer which contains many thousand polygons>
i am going to operate an intersect loop for every point in the layer with near polygons.
i use

```
ITopologicalOperator op = (ITopologicalOperator) pGeometry;
Geometry intersectionResult = op.intersect(getPolygonFeature(), esriGeometryDimension.esriGeometry0Dimension);
```

but the problem is that the intersect operator will work on all the POLYGON layer 
so i am looking for splitting or partitioning the layer to smaller partitions >
and apply the intersect between every point with only on part.
so is there any way to do it in java arcobject?

[image: Example]

PS:
i use arcgis 10.1
polygon layer has more than 100000 polygons 
my code must get the intersect between every point in the study area 
and the polygons around it ,within a Specified radius (100 meters for example)
Partitioning means: i don't want to apply the intersect with all polygons in layer every time,
cause the most of them are out of the -Circle around the point -
i added a picture for 4 random point

in order to use the ITopologicalOperator  i use a function to union the polygons:

```
IPolygon polygonUnion(IFeatureClass featureClass) throws Exception {

    //Check input objects.
    if (featureClass == null) {
        return null;
    }

    IGeoDataset geoDataset = (IGeoDataset) featureClass;
    ISpatialFilter queryFilter = new SpatialFilter();

    //Set the properties of the spatial filter here.
    IGeometry geometryBag = new GeometryBag();

    //Define the spatial reference of the bag before adding geometries to it.
    geometryBag.setSpatialReferenceByRef(spatialReference);
   // geometryBag.setSpatialReferenceByRef(geoDataset.getSpatialReference());
    //Use a nonrecycling cursor so each returned geometry is a separate object. 
    IFeatureCursor featureCursor = featureClass.search(queryFilter, false);

    IGeometryCollection geometryCollection = (IGeometryCollection) geometryBag;
    IFeature currentFeature = featureCursor.nextFeature();

    while (currentFeature != null) {
        //Add a reference to this feature's geometry into the bag.
        //You don't specify the before or after geometry (missing),
        //so the currentFeature.Shape IGeometry is added to the end of the geometryCollection.
        Polygon polygon = (Polygon) currentFeature.getShape();

        geometryCollection.addGeometry(currentFeature.getShape(), null, null);

        currentFeature = featureCursor.nextFeature();
    }

    // Create the polygon that will be the union of the features returned from the search cursor.
    // The spatial reference of this feature does not need to be set ahead of time. The 
    // ConstructUnion method defines the constructed polygon's spatial reference to be the same as 
    // the input geometry bag.
    ITopologicalOperator unionedPolygon = new Polygon();
    unionedPolygon.constructUnion((IEnumGeometry) geometryBag);

    return (IPolygon) unionedPolygon;
}
```

Comment: You've left out a lot of important information, including the version of ArcGIS, the actual number of features, the feature class source datatype, the presence of a spatial Index, the physical ordering of both feature classes, what you mean by "partioning",...

Comment: i use arcgis 10.1
polygon layer has more than 100000 polygons 
my code must get the intersect between every point in the study area 
and the polygons around it ,within a Specified radius (100 meters for example)
Partitioning means: i don't want to apply the intersect with all polygons in layer every time,
cause the most of them are out of the -Circle around the point -
i added a picture for 4 random point

Comment: An intersection operator is likely to use a spatial index, so it doesn't really matter how many features there are, just how many vertices are in the features whose envelopes overlap the point.

Comment: i tested the intersect for smaller polygon layer and it works. when i test it for large layer i got a memory full fail

Comment: Then this question should have been addressing that error, with the full contents of the output and full error message.  You still need to edit the question to specify the data storage format (shapefile, FGDB, enterprise geodatabase, in-memory geodatabase,...) of the layers.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a Polygon x Point intersection? If so, your code seems correct. Your picture clearly shows a set of polygons (buildings, in yellowish) and another set of polygons (in red).

It's not clear from your question, where the problem is. Is the polygon intersection failing?

If that is the case (buffered points, which are in turn, polygons), your code is incorrect. According to this doc (http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/ArcObjects/esriGeometry/esriGeometryDimension.htm) you should use either:

- esriGeometry2Dimension;
- esriGeometryNoDimension;

Like so:

```
ITopologicalOperator op = (ITopologicalOperator) pGeometry;
Geometry intersectionResult = op.intersect(getPolygonFeature(), esriGeometryDimension.esriGeometry2Dimension);
```

Comment: the picture shows red polygons which are the  vision field for  a point ,i calculate that field of vision by getting the intersect : -point,near polygons(buildings, in yellowish)-     ,the result is a collection of points which i show as red polygon.   all the process is correct when i have a polygon layer (building) with small number of polygons.  and  the process fails "full memory" when i apply it for huge layer (all the city)

Comment: for the point i apply the intersect many times using different angle everytime, so i can get intersect for 36 times-for example- to get the field of vision,, then i create a new polygon using the 36 intersects results.